# Opening a TCL gui within Java code

Tags: java, tcl, jacl, bwidget

I have a TCL file which uses Tcl's BWidget package that I've been using as a GUI for my program. I now want to be able to load up this GUI from a separate Java program. I've looked into Jacl and Swank, but they don't seem to do exactly what I want.

I've tried the following with Jacl but it's unable to evaluate the file. While debugging, I can see that it completes parsing my tcl file, but it throws an exception while parsing through the BWidget package tcl files. Here's my Java code:

```
Interp interp = new Interp();
try {
    interp.evalFile("C:\\CTP\\Tcl\\LuxonCtp32.tcl");
} catch (TclException ex) {
    int code = ex.getCompletionCode();
    System.err.println("command returned bad error code: " + code);
} finally {
    interp.dispose();
}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish what I want to do? Is it even possible?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: It might be easier to run the GUI in a subprocess (see `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`); Java's subprocess handling is not really all that great, but it beats working with a large chunk of unported code!

Comment: @DonalFellows Thank you for the help. I simply started the tcl wish shell in a subprocess and executed my tcl script.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl itself can not display a GUI. It uses a plugin called Tk for that.
In the C reference implementation of Tcl you get Tk as well.
Tk has not been ported to Java, Tcl has.

You can not use Jacl to display Tk widgets, but [TclBlend](http://tcljava.sourceforge.net/docs/website/index.html) could do that, because TclBlend uses the C reference implementation of Tcl. That means that the user needs a working Tcl/Tk installation.

There are some problems with TclBlend and Tcl > 8.5 through, which result in a segfault.
IIRC you have to remove the conditional `if` around `Tcl_FindNameOfExecutable` in TclBlends C code (and compile it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site http://jtcl-project.github.io/jtcl/ and download now for the binary zip. Its a recent java tcl on github called Jtcl.
Unzip it and you will find a jar called jtcl-2.7.0.jar.
I am using Netbeans 8 my preference.
I add the jar into Project Library.
I create a java file called JTclHallo.java and this is the code.

```
package jtclhallo;
// import tcl.lang it belongs to jtcl-2.7.0 jar a must

import tcl.lang.*;

 // Java wrapper to test JACL or JTCL.

public class JTclHallo {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        //Interp is a java class belonging to tcl.lang. Unrar the jtcl-2.7.0

        Interp i = new Interp();


        try {

            //call your tcl file mine was swing.tcl from the E drive
            i.eval("source E:/private/swing.tcl");
            } catch (TclException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }

    }
 }
```

For swing.tcl

```
package require java

set window [java::new javax.swing.JFrame]
$window setSize 600 400
$window setVisible true
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in a few sentences instead of simply dumping the code inhere?